# Iphone 4 VS. 4s wifi data upload speed difference

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, wifi

I'm seeing significant speed differences in the upload speeds between the 4 and the 4s. While uploading a 50MB file via FTP, I'm seeing about a 125KBs difference, and it's talking about a minute less for the 4s to complete the upload. I should note that the 4 is on iOS 5.0 and the 4s is on 5.1. I've read here http://www.anandtech.com/show/4971/apple-iphone-4s-review-att-verizon/9 that the 4s has had some significant wifi upgrades, but the benchmark is only for download. Does anyone have an explanation for this, or is it simply the chip upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the upgrade processors. It could also be an upgrade in how the phone operates when connected to the internet.